# How to get the 'bool' value from a Future<bool> into a field variable, for later use

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I am using `flutter_blue` package for using the Bluetooth service. I want to check whether the device has Bluetooth capabilities. The method `isAvailable` seems to do it. However, it returns a Future<bool>, which I am tryting to get into a variable as follows:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';

class BT_Base {

final FlutterBlue _fb = FlutterBlue.instance;
bool BTAvailable = true;     // as a default placeholder

BT_Base () {
    BTAvailable = _fixAvail();
}

_fixAvail () async {
  return await _fb.isAvailable;
}

...
```

I try to get the future value from it and store into `BTAvailable`. Later on, I use the fixed `BTAvailable` field to get the appropriate Widget to be passed onto as follows:

```dart
class BTDevicePrompt extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BT_Base bt = BT_Base();
    var btDeviceRes = bt.scan();

    if(!bt.BTAvailable) return Text('Bluetooth unavailable on device...');
    else if (btDeviceRes.isEmpty) return Text('No Bluetooth devices in range...');
    else {
      return CupertinoActionSheet(
        actions: [
                  ...
                 ],
      )
    }
  }
}
```

But I keep getting the error `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool'` at runtime. How can I use the Future properly in this situation? It is alright if the whole process just halts and waits for this part as well.

I have gone through a lot of solutions but I am not able to piece it together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any method marked `async` always returns a `Future` of some kind. You can give it an explicit return type like `Future<bool> function() async { ... }`, or if you leave it out it will infer `Future<dynamic>`.

In short, you can't get a `bool` from a `Future<bool>` outside of an `async` function (there are technically ways but almost certainly not what you want in Flutter).

This makes sense, since the whole point of a `Future<bool>` is that it's going to be a `bool` *in the future*. If there was some process to convert from a `Future<bool>` to a `bool`, what should it do if the future has not yet completed? Perhaps it should wait until it has completed. In that case, you're just describing the `await` keyword.

If, however, you want to use a `Future` in your UI in a Flutter application, you have a few options.

The simplest for your case will be to move it into `initState()`:

```dart
class BTDevicePrompt extends StatefulWidget {
  // stateful widget boilerplate
}

class BTDevicePromptState extends State<BTDevicePrompt> {
  bool isAvailable = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkAvailable();  // use a helper method because initState() cannot be async
  }

  Future<void> checkAvailable() async {
    // call an async function and wait for it to complete
    bool result = await checkIfBluetoothAvailable();
    setState(() => bluetoothAvailable = result);  // set the local variable
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (bluetoothAvailable) return Text('bluetooth available');
    else return Text('bluetooth not available');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. I now have a better undertainding of States and Futures!